# Does SLAB memory allocator perform better than SLUB allocator on NUMA systems?

Tags: c, linux, memory, memory-management, linux-kernel

I was reading the article at https://lists.debian.org/debian-kernel/2012/03/msg00944.html

This article says that SLAB allocator will perform better as compared to SLUB allocator when the allocation of memory is done on 1 NUMA node and de-allocation is done on another NUMA node.

I know that SLUB & SLAB differ in terms of maintenance of object-queues (meta-data).

But can anyone explain why SLAB is expected to perform better on NUMA systems ?
(specifically on Linux kernel 4.7.10)

Any help is appreciated